# Is it possible to have two mailboxes(folders) with same name?

Tags: python, email, smtp, imap, mail-server

I am working on a product where I have to interact with email servers (like zimbra, dovecot etc) through IMAP to fetch emails etc.

I am using Python's imaplib library. I connect to email server account with credentials and then select a mailbox (folder) through its name.

Now I am wondering whether is it possible to have two mailboxes with same name in an account? If yes then how to go about it ?

Comment: Mailbox names could be the same, but **real** Folder Names couldn't. Check if you really deal with Folder Names.

Comment: I am probably unclear on this. Before fetching an email, I have to select the folder (or mailbx - not clear) first through its name [like this imap_instance.select(folder_name) ] and then go for fetching the mail. So I think it will be the real folder, but still not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: I am probably unclear on this.

Using `select(mailbox=...` you are dealing with **Real Folders**.
Therefore **no** duplicate possible.

> [IMAP4.select(mailbox=’INBOX’, readonly=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4.select)
>
> Select a mailbox.
>     Returned data is the count of messages in mailbox (EXISTS response).
>     The default mailbox is 'INBOX'.
>     If the readonly flag is set, modifications to the mailbox are not allowed.